# How can I use localStorage to save form data (text, textarea & checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

I have a huge form with a **lot** of inputs, textareas, and checkboxes. The form has a captcha on it. I want to save the form answers locally with `localStorage` so that if the captcha returns `fail`, their form data will be repopulated.

**HTML**

```
<form name="wellnessForm" id="wellnessForm" action="confirm.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="noConcernsChk[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="noConcernsChk[]" value="2" />
  <br/>
  <textarea>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
// DOM ready
$(function(){
    $(':text').blur(function(e){
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
        var data = $('#wellnessForm').serializeArray();
        $.each(data, function(i, obj){
            localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);  
        });
    });
    $(':checkbox').click(function(e){
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
        var data = $('#wellnessForm').serializeArray();
        $.each(data, function(i, obj){
            localStorage.setItem(obj.value, e.checked);
        });
    });

    // test if there is already saved data
    if( localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set" ){

        var data = $("#wellnessForm").serializeArray();

        // have to select the valid inputs based on their name attribute
        $.each(data, function(i, obj){

            // check if checkbox
            if(obj.name == 'noConcernsChk[]'){
                $( "[value='"+obj.value+"']:checkbox" ).prop('checked', true);
            }
            else{
                $("[name='" + obj.name + "']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
            }

        }); 
    }

    // provide mechanism to remove data (TODO: remove actual data not just kill the flag)
    $("#clearData").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "");
    });

});
```

<sup>[Source on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fijzI)</sup>

**How far I got**
As you can see by my example, I have text inputs working. However I'm stuck on checkboxes. I would like to have the `localStorage` remember if the boxes were checked or not, and if they were, re-check them in the form for the user. I also haven't gotten textarea working yet but that shouldn't be too hard.

**Question**
How can you store checkbox state to local storage, and then recall it (and have the proper boxes checked)?

Comment: you should include some of the code in your question here... a link is fine but provide some actual code, too

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that! Edited.

Comment: You need something to differentiate the checkboxes, e.g. different names.

Comment: @simonzack: There are many checkboxes and they are grouped together because of their relation ( noConcernsChk[] is the group name ), and their values are all different. It's set up this way for server-side handling. Should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage can store only string values.

first of all, you have to serialize the data use [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), then you can store it like

`localStorage['data']=$('form').serialize()`

**edit**

For restore, you have make some rules.Add `data-binding` to tag, save form value as key/value pair, the key is `data-binding`, then you can restore it.

Something like this

```
var data = {};
$('[data-binding]')
.each(function(){ data[$(this).data('binding')] = $(this).serialize(); })

localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(data);
```

For restore

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage['data']);
$('[data-binding]')
    .each(function()
    { 
         // handle the set value
         // need consider the different value type for different field type


         var $this = $(this);
         var val = data[$this.data('binding')];

         // for chechbox
         if($this.is('[type=checkbox]'))
            $this.prop('checked',val)
        // for others
        else
            $this.val(val);


    })
```

Example in my code:

```
// u5 = utils
U5 = {};

/**
 * 加载配置到界面,data-setting属性指定setting项
 * @param setting
 */
U5['LoadSettingToUI'] = function (setting)
{
    $('[data-setting]')
        .each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var val;
            val = setting[$this.data('setting')];
            // 根据不同的类型进行值的转换 for jquery mobile
            if($this.is('select[data-role=slider]'))// 这里没有使用jqmData来判断,考虑兼容问题
            {
                $this.val(val?'on':'off');
            }else if($this.is('[type=checkbox]'))
            {
                $this.prop('checked',!!val);
            }else{
                $this.val(val);
            }
        });
};
/**
 * 从页面获取配置,data-setting属性指定setting项
 * @return {object}
 */
U5['GetSettingFromUI'] = function ()
{
    var setting = {};
    $('[data-setting]').each(function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        /**
         * @type {string|boolean}
         */
        var val;
        val = $this.val();
        // 根据不同的类型进行值的转换
        if(/^on|off$/.test(val))
        {
            val = val === 'on';
        }else if($this.is('[type=checkbox]'))
        {
            val = $this.prop('checked');
        }
        //
        setting[$this.data('setting')] = val;
    });
    return setting;
};
```

**Full demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wener/X5zpe/)**

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. for the data-binding, do I just add that to the inputs like follows?
`<input type="checkbox" data-binding="checkbox" />`?

Comment: no, data-binding is the name of the data, also, you can use name instead, this will be more convenience for form field. I use data-binding for other tags, like div.

Comment: I have my checkboxes named `noConcernChk[]`, and they all have unique `values`, this is so they will be grouped together on my server-side handling. My code works already for text inputs, however I'm not sure how to store/retrieve the checked state of the checkboxes.

Comment: I add a sample to restore the form field.

Comment: add a full demo.In the demo, submit will save value to localStorage,after you reset, you can restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an existing plugin.

For example [persisto](https://github.com/mar10/persisto) is an open source project that provides an easy interface to localStorage/sessionStorage and automates persistence for form fields (input, radio buttons, and checkboxes).
(Disclaimer: I am the author.)

[image: persisto features]

Note that this requires jQuery as a dependency.

For example:

```
<form name="wellnessForm" id="wellnessForm" action="confirm.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="noConcernsChk[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="noConcernsChk[]" value="2" />
  <br/>
  <textarea name="detailsText">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

could be handled like this:

```
// Maintain client's preferences in localStorage:
var store = PersistentObject("wellnessData");

// Initialize form elements with currently stored data
store.writeToForm("#wellnessForm");

// Allow users to edit and save settings:
$("#wellnessForm").submit(function(e){
  // ... maybe some validations here ...
  store.readFromForm(this);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```